# large virtual lists in Swing using AbstractListModel -- limit at 119,000,000 items?

Tags: java, swing

I've got my "virtual list" in swing working well, but it seems to fail when I exceed some particular number of items. By "fail" I mean that the scroll bar magically vanishes when the number of items is > Nmax, and it comes back when the number of items is <= Nmax; Nmax seems to be somewhere around 119,304,000 on my system.

What am I running up against?!?!

(Here's a test program: on my computer, if I type in 119,304 it works ok, but I click the up arrow and the scroll bar disappears)

```
package com.example.test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.AbstractListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerModel;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

// based on:
// http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/extendsAbstractListModel.htm
// http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/SpinnerNumberModel.htm
// http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html
// http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/ListeningforJSpinnerEventswithaChangeListener.htm
// http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/tech_topics/jlist_1/jlist.html

public class BigVirtualList extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BigVirtualList();
    }

    static final int initialLength = 1;
    final private JList list1 = new JList();
    final private BVLData bvldata = new BVLData(initialLength*1000);

    public BigVirtualList() {
        this.setTitle("Big virtual list");
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        list1.setModel(bvldata);

        list1.setPrototypeCellValue(list1.getModel().getElementAt(0));


        SpinnerModel model1 = new SpinnerNumberModel(initialLength,1,1000000,1);
        final JSpinner spinner1 = new JSpinner(model1);

        this.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(list1), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Length (1000s of items):");
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel1.add(label1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        panel1.add(spinner1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.getContentPane().add(panel1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);      

        ChangeListener listener = new ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                Integer newLength = (Integer)spinner1.getValue();
                bvldata.setLength(newLength*1000);
            }
        };

        spinner1.addChangeListener(listener);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}

class BVLData extends AbstractListModel {
    public BVLData(int length) { this.length = length; }

    private int length;

    public int getLength() { return length; }
    public void setLength(int length) {
        int oldLength = getLength();
        this.length = length;
        int newLength = getLength();

        if (newLength > oldLength)
            fireIntervalAdded(this, oldLength+1, newLength);
        else if (newLength < oldLength)
            fireIntervalRemoved(this, newLength+1, oldLength);      
    }   

    @Override
    public Object getElementAt(int index) {
        return "Item "+index+" mod 107 = "+(index%107);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize() { return getLength(); }

}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you need a 119,000,000-item list?

Comment: It's a virtual list, the items aren't necessarily all actually stored. Or it could be a sparse list (e.g. with "blank" elements at most items, but real items at elements 1-1000, and 12000000-12100000, and 207300000-207400000). I'm messing around w/ visualizing streams of data.

Comment: Anyway the exact # isn't so much the point, as I want to know what drives this limit -- maybe on some systems it's much lower, say at 3,000,000.

Comment: FYI, my system also fails at the 119304/119305 barrier.

Comment: Why do you prepend all method calls with "this"?

Comment: @James Van Huis: That's because the maximum size of Java ints on your system is also 2147483647. Which it had better be.

Comment: @Steve Kuo: I adapted this program from an example, the example used "this" in the way you're talking about. I can't really think of a reason to do so; member variables it makes sense to disambiguate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I don't see the purpose but anyway ...

I guess you break the integer max value somewhere in the scroll pane:

```
System.out.println("CellHeight:"+list1.getFixedCellHeight());
System.out.println("CellHeight*119304000:"+NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(list1.getFixedCellHeight()*119304000.0));
System.out.println("MAXINT:"+Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Gives you the numbers:

```
CellHeight:18
CellHeight*119304000:2.147.472.000
MAXINT:2.147.483.647
```

As you can see adding another 18000 pixel in height will go beyond MAXINT ... this gets you in trouble.

Comment: +1: I was coming to the same conclusion. 2^31 / 18 ~= 119304647.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. So the list actually tries to render items as if it were a very large canvas, each item in their proper place?

Comment: +1: I just added the line "list1.setFixedCellHeight(10);" and now it goes to 214,748.

Comment: Most probably the list does not render all items on a virtual canvas. I guess the scroll bar bounds will be set to 0...maxheight. If the height exceeds the positive integer max value it overflows to the negative and the scroll bar is "no longer needed"

Comment: So if I implemented a scrollbar that used long rather than int, it would work? (I'm looking at ways to navigate among large datasets & knowing these limits is sortof important... the scrollbar doesn't work too well to move accurately. reminds me of struggling w/ microfiche viewers.)

Comment: Well, I think reimplementing a scroll bar using long might be possible (or do the scroll management yourself use a scrollbar and a factor). I would try to think of other possibilities to navigate since its not really usable with a scrollbar anyway

Comment: yeah, maybe a pair of scrollbars (coarse+fine "zoom"), and a spinner for random-access.